# Jquery/coffee script 500 error in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am new to Jquery to trying to understand a rails app I am working on. I have an email form, where you send an invoice, and the recipient can dispute the invoice, but The dispute send form is giving a 500 error and,

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data )
```

and

```
if ( callback && ( isAbort || xhr.readyState === 4 ) ) {
```

When I refresh the page the action is being logged, the invoice reads as having been disputed, but the actions that should happen (actually sending the note and a success message) are not happening.

This is the relevant js.erb file

```
jQuery('#dispute_invoice_popup').modal('hide');
jQuery(".alert.alert-success").show().find('span').html("<%= escape_javascript @message %>");
jQuery('.response_to_client').html('<%= escape_javascript render("dispute_history") %>');
jQuery('#show_invoice_container').html('<%= escape_javascript render("show_invoice") %>');
```

This is the relevant section of the HTML file

```
<div class="dispute_popup">
<%= form_tag "/invoices/dispute_invoice",:class=>"dispute_form",:novalidate => "", :remote => true do %>
<div id="dispute_invoice_popup" class="modal hide fad" style="width:760px; min-height: 250px; left:43.4%;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="model_grey_container">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h1><%= t('views.invoices.dispute_invoice') %></h1>
      <div class="cross_btn">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
          <%= image_tag "cross.png", :size => "7x7", :alt => "" %>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="invoice_popup_error" class="alert alert-error popup" style="display:none;">
      <button class="close" type="button" style="margin:0px;">×</button>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= hidden_field_tag "invoice_id", @invoice.id %>
      <div class="fields_content_data new_invoice_fields">
        <div class="field_row textarea">
          <div class="label_field textarea"><label><%= t('views.invoices.reason_for_dispute') %></label></div>
          <div class="large_field" style="clear:both;">
            <%= text_area_tag "reason_for_dispute" ,'',:required => ""%>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer ">
      <%= submit_tag t("views.common.send"), :class => "btn_large submit" %>
      <a class="btn_large grey" href="#" data-dismiss="modal"><%= t('views.common.cancel') %></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

These are in the js.coffee file

```
# dispute popup validation
jQuery("form.dispute_form").submit ->
flag = true
if jQuery("#reason_for_dispute").val() is ""
  applyPopover(jQuery("#reason_for_dispute"),"bottomMiddle","topLeft","Enter reason for dispute")
  flag = false
flag
jQuery("#reason_for_dispute").live "keyup", ->
jQuery(this).qtip("hide")

# Alert on dispute if invoice is paid
jQuery('#dispute_link').click ->
jQuery('#reason_for_dispute').val('')
flag = true
status = jQuery(this).attr "value"
if status is "paid"
  alert "Paid invoice can not be disputed."
  flag = false
flag

jQuery(".more").live "click", ->
jQuery(".toggleable").removeClass("collapse")
```

As I said, I'm new to Jquery and I'm really at a loss here, I'd really appreciate any help or advice. If there is any other information that you might need, let me know.

Comment: It's impossible to make sense of your Coffeescript code without proper indenting.

Comment: ...you should also include the 500 error you're receiving (and at least the first few lines of the stacktrace)